# Android Studio Action Bar - Compiler "guesses" wrong library in xml

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-menu

So I was trying to add some menu items to the action bar and I saw that you have to use:

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item app:showAsAction="ifRoom" ... />
</menu>
```

but the code doesn't work for me. That is the code for AppCompat but I am using the default action bar (Theme Holo + no support libraries). For this reason I have to use:

```
<item android:showAsAction="ifRoom" ... />
```

which works. But the compiler (Android Studio) doesn't know that I'm not using AppCompat and says the following error message:

```
Should use app:showAsAction with the appcompat library ... more stuff
```

I tried setting the tools:context to my class but it simply doesn't want to understand. I managed to solve it by adding a tools ignore (with `AppCompatResource`) but I don't like fixing with suppresses and I don't know if this might cause errors on older / newer / some devices.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the message is based on your dependencies. If you are not using the support library, remove it from your `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! But is there any way to make it "know" that I'm using the default activity, not `ActionBarActivity` and fix that error without removing the library?